# Git - Commit failed with error: branch is up-to-date, but there are actually changes to be committed

Tags: git, android-studio, svn, version-control

The issue I'm asking about is only the third step of a big conundrum for me.

1. All started with the .gitignore file which wasn't working.
   I googled and I found that typing `git rm -r --cached .` at the top folder of my repo, and then `git add .` after editing my .gitignore file and committing everything should have worked.
2. But, when trying to commit everything I received a commit error (and consequent failure) message due to the warning:

   > LF will be replaced by CRLF

   I then googled again and: checked if `core.autocrlf` was true (and it was) and tried making the warning go away with `git congif --global core.safecrlf false`.

This brings me to the third and last step

3. When I tried to finally commit my .gitignore changes to my repo, I received from the IDE:

   > Commit failed with error 0 files committed, 1462 files failed to commit: Fixes .gitignore
   >
   > On branch develop
   >   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
   >   nothing to commit, working directory clean

This is, though, what I get from `git status` for all my 1462 files:

> On branch develop
>
> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
>
> Changes to be committed:
>     (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
>
> deleted:    .idea/vcs.xml
>   modified:   app/.gitignore
>   deleted:    app/app.iml
>   deleted:    app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/androidTest/debug/com/android_
>   application/adiuvapp_verbalatina/test/BuildConfig.java

I think that at this point I should use `git reset HEAD...` but I really don't want mess anything up!

How can I solve this?

Comment: So for step3, you commit changes from android studio? What if you commit changes from git bash?

Comment: It actually solved the problem! I feel extremely stupid for not having tried this solution.
Post your comment as an answer! Could you explain why it worked this way, though?

Comment: Yes, I added an answer just now, and explained the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For step3, you can try to use git commit in git bash instead of android studio.

Since git bash is the original and more comprehensive functional than other IDE integrate with git, and you  made some changes which to stop some files to be version controlled by git (the feature is not used in android studio), so it can’t well detected these changes.